# Is this correct way to apply darboux thereom

Tags: calculus

Say we have a function $f$ that is differentiable on $[0, \infty )$ and $f'$ is not bounded. Then can I conclude that $f'$ is surjective on that range ?ie, If I was asked if there exists a point c such that f'(c)=100 or d such that $f'(d)=20000$, then would the answer be simply yes because of darboux thereom and since $f'$ isn't  bounded? Thanks

Comment: The derivative might never be smaller than $10000$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, AND the derivative is zero at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add (as in a comment) that $f'(0)=0$, or at least that $f'(x)$ is $0$ somewhere. You also want to specify that $f'$ is not bounded *above*.

Then  $f'$ takes on all values in $[0,\infty)$ by the Intermediate Value Property (Darboux's Theorem). The proof is along the lines you described. To show $f'$ takes on the value $b\gt 0$, pick an $m$ such that $f'(m)\gt b$. Then $f'$ takes on all values between $0$ and $m$, in particular the value $b$. Of course $f'$ might be negative some places.